# Compare two xmls using xquery

Tags: xquery

I have two xmls, say Sample1.xml and Sample2.xml. Now I need to compare both the xml values (parent nodes, child nodes, attributes and its values) and return the differences between them in xquery. I knew I can use deep-equal function to say if the xmls are identical. But I do not know how to compare and return the xml difference.

Please help.

Thanks,
-N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the degree of generality we're talking about here, this is a [non-trivial problem](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/niagara/papers/xdiff.pdf) (PDF).  If your question is, "how do I write this algorithm," then it's way too open-ended for StackOverflow (see the FAQ).  If, on the other hand, you are asking, "Is there any XQuery library code out there that will do this," then it appears that simply Googling "XML difference XQuery" will lead you straight to [the answer](https://blogs.oracle.com/knutvatsendvik/entry/xmldiff_with_xquery).  Faster, even, then having someone else do the Googling for you on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks man, I was expecting an algorithm and finally have arrived at it.

Comment: When someone answers your question on Stack Overflow, you're supposed to accept their answer, so that they can earn reputation points.  So...  http://stackoverflow.com/about